# In Corda, how can I configure a node's web port when using the node driver?

Tags: corda

I am using the Corda node driver to start a node. How can I configure the node's web port?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass in a custom override for the `webAddress` property.

In the example below, we set the node's web port to `12345`:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    driver {
        val nodeHandle = startNode(
                customOverrides = mapOf("webAddress" to "localhost:12345")
        ).getOrThrow()

        startWebserver(nodeHandle).get()
    }
}
```